# using strace to debug db2 CLI executing a query

Tags: shell, db2, strace, db2-luw

I would like to use `strace` to debug a strange behaviour I have with `db2`. I have a SQL function `myFoo()` implemented in `C` that doesn't get called for some reason (some code access path not existing or not authorized see [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54173/db2-cannot-execute-c-function-for-reason-code-4)). My Sql Function call a function `Foo`in shared library in `/usr/local/lib/libmyfoo` (so in db2 term `/usr/local/lib/libmyfoo!Foo`).

If I use `strace` directly with db2 and the query I have an error saying

```
   A database connection does not exist
```

so i created a script call `debug.sh` with the following. The idea is to have a shell with the db2 connection active and trace it.

```
db2 "connect to MYDB"
db2 "select * from table(myFoo())" # this calls /usr/local/lib/libmyfoo!Foo
db2 "disconnect MYDB"
```

It doesn't work cos I realized that strace works with binary so I have the error

```
Exec Format Error
```

Comment: I don't think `strace`ing the client will help you debug the server.

Comment: What's the output of `ls -l /usr/local/lib/libmyfoo` (and please stop using bogus names, noone is going to steal your intellectual property by knowing the actual file name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are calling each DB2 command in different subshells.
You can fix that problem by executing everything in just one subshell, for example

```
VALUE=$(. /home/db2inst1/sqllib/db2profile ; db2 connect to MYDB ; db2 "select * from table(myFoo())")
```

Comment: Hi Ancgoca. Thanks for your help. I can see the result assigned to $VALUE, but how can I use strace with that? I am struggling a bit (tough I am still searching for ways to use your call)

Answer (score 0):

> My Sql Function call a function Foo in shared library in `/usr/local/lib/libmyfoo` (so in db2 term `libmyfoo!Foo`).

Is this really how you defined your function? `libmyfoo!Foo` will point to the library `$INSTANCE_HOME/sqllib/function/libmyfoo`. If your library is elsewhere you need to provide the absolute path to it.

Comment: I have updated the post. I did it the right way resepcting the path. Sorry for the lack of accuracy in my post.